# ffprobe how to retrieve both audio and video info and output to single line?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I can use the following to retrieve the audio and video codec and the video frame  height:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=index,codec_name,height -of csv input.mp4
```

But the output is on two lines and includes text that I don't need like so:

```
stream,0,h264,720
stream,1,mp3
```

The only output I want is to be in the form of:

```
mp3,h264,720
```

I've tried using -show_entries twice in the same command line, but it ignores the first call every time.  I've also tried using

```
ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v -show_entries stream=codec_name,height, -select_streams a -show_entries stream=codec_name
```

but that doesn't do anything.

How can I get the simplified output as specified above?

Comment: Conforming only to your example, `ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=codec_name,height -of csv input.mp4 | powershell "$i=$input|select;[array]::reverse($i);$i -join ',' -replace '( |stream,)'"` would work.  But what will it do to your logic if your video file contains the audio as stream 0 and the video as stream 1?  Or if stream 0 includes the video, stream 1 includes DTS 5.1 audio in English, stream 2 has AC3 2.0 audio in French, and stream 3 has subtitles in mjpeg format as a video stream?  How will you programmatically determine the data you need in the order you need?

Comment: There are only 3 things I'm looking for: 1) Is the frame height 720 or greater?  If yes, proceed with the next two checks.  2) is it h264?  if not, re-encode to h264.  2) Is the audio aac?  If not, then also re-encode the audio..

Comment: Ack!  I meant h265.....

Comment: JSON is an idea which would give more freedom, but I don't know much about it.  I notice then when I output to the JSON format I get a section in the streams for disposition.  How do I prevent that from showing?  I just need to do `ffprobe -show_streams -show_entries stream=height,codec_name -of json -v quiet -i input.mp4` to get the info that I showed before.

Comment: Seems to me that you just objectify your JSON data, then parse.  `while (!height) { height = streams[i++].height || 0 }` or similar, depending on language.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "codec=" & set "sound="
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('ffprobe ... ') do (
  for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=," %%a in (%%i) do (
   if not defined codec (
      set "codec=%%a"
      set "hres=%%b"
    ) else (
      if not defined sound set "sound=%%a"
    )
  )
)
echo %sound%,%codec%,%hres%
```

if there are blank lines before `ffprobe` output, you should add the `skip=n` keyword to `for` loop.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to run strictly from ffprobe or is it impossible to get the output on a single line without parsing it as shown in the answer?

Comment: @gregm, I don't know nothing about `ffprobe`, sorry. what I know is that any output may be grabbed with a `for` loop, all we have to do is parse this output to get the desired results. anyway, this is a `batch processing` site, don't forget it, some solutions may seem not easy, but, once you know the constrains your task have, you may create a general tool to work with.

Answer (score 0):

After our conversation in the comments, I think something like this is what you're looking for.  It's a Batch + JScript hybrid script.  I'm using JScript to parse and objectify the JSON output by `ffprobe`.  Salt to taste, and remove `echo` from line 31 when you're ready for the script to act.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal & goto run

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 infile outfile
echo This script re-encodes videos to x265 + AAC encoding.
exit /b

:run
if "%~2"=="" goto usage
if not exist "%~1" goto usage

set ffprobe=ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries "stream=codec_name,height" -of json "%~1"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%ffprobe% ^| cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"') do set "%%~I"

if %height% lss 720 (
    echo Video is ^< 720p.  Not worth it.
    exit /b
)

set "pre=-hide_banner -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt+fastseek -analyzeduration 100M"
set "pre=%pre% -probesize 50M -hwaccel dxva2 -y -threads 3 -v error -stats"
set "global="
set "video=-c:v libx265 -crf 22 -preset fast"
set "audio=-c:a libfdk_aac -flags +qscale -global_quality 4 -afterburner 1"

if defined hevc if defined aac (
    echo Already in x265 + AAC format.
    exit /b
)

if defined aac (
    echo Already has AAC audio.  Re-encoding video only.
    set "audio=-c:a copy"
) else if defined hevc (
    echo Already has x265 video.  Re-encoding audio only.
    set "video=-c:v copy"
)

echo ffmpeg %pre% -i "%~1" %global% %video% %audio% "%~2"

goto :EOF
@end // end Batch / begin JScript

var stdin = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(0),
    htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    JSON;

htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
htmlfile.close(JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON);

var obj = JSON.parse(stdin.ReadAll());

for (var i = obj.streams.length; i--;) {
    if (obj.streams[i].height) WSH.Echo('height=' + obj.streams[i].height);
    if (/hevc/i.test(obj.streams[i].codec_name)) WSH.Echo('hevc=true');
    if (/aac/i.test(obj.streams[i].codec_name)) WSH.Echo('aac=true');
}
```

Comment: Wow, that definitely looks like it will work.  I certainly wasn't expecting anyone to do all that coding.  I'll be back home next Tuesday and will try it out.  Thanks for the time you put into this!