# Recursively run ffprobe to get codec types

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I modified [@rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo) code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086424/ffprobe-how-to-retrieve-both-audio-and-video-info-and-output-to-single-line) a little to look for h264/AC3 and to recursively run thru all the children folders. My only issue is that it always says the videos has h264 and AC3, but when I run the ffprobe command manually it states different. Am I missing something?

```bash
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

for /R %%f in (*.mkv, *.mp4) do (
    echo Testing %%f

    set ffprobe=C:\ffmpeg-4.0.2-win64-static\bin\ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries "stream=codec_name,height" -of json "%%f"

    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%ffprobe% ^| cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"') do set "%%~I"

    set "pre=-hide_banner -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt+fastseek -analyzeduration 100M"
    set "pre=%pre% -probesize 50M -hwaccel dxva2 -y -threads 3 -v error -stats"
    set "global="
    set "video=-c:v h264_nvenc"
    set "audio=-c:a ac3"

    if defined h264 if defined ac3 (
        echo %%~nf already in x264 + AC3 format.
    )

    if not defined h264 if not defined ac3 (

        if not defined ac3 (
            echo Already has AC3 audio.  Re-encoding video only.
            set "audio=-c:a copy"
        ) 

        if not defined h264 (
            echo Already has h264 video.  Re-encoding audio only.
            set "video=-c:v copy"
        )

        echo output "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.new.mkv"
        echo C:\ffmpeg-4.0.2-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg %pre% -i "%%f" %global% %video% %audio% "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.new.mkv"

        pause

        echo del "%%f" /f /q
        echo ren "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.new.mkv" "%%f"
    )

)
@end // end Batch / begin JScript

var stdin = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(0),
    htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    JSON;

htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
htmlfile.close(JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON);

var obj = JSON.parse(stdin.ReadAll());

for (var i = obj.streams.length; i--;) {
    if (/h264/i.test(obj.streams[i].codec_name)) WSH.Echo('h264=true');
    if (/ac3/i.test(obj.streams[i].codec_name)) WSH.Echo('ac3=true');
}
```

I had this working of a second then it stopped for not reason.

```bash
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal & goto run

:run
for /R %%f in (*.mkv, *.mp4) do (
    echo Testing %%f

    set "file=%%f"
    set "drive=%%~df"
    set "dir=%%~pf"
    set "name=%%~nf"
    set "ext=%%~xf"

    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('C:\ffmpeg-4.0.2-win64-static\bin\ffprobe.exe -v quiet -show_entries "stream=codec_name,height" -of json "%%f" ^| cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"') do (set "%%~I")

    set "pre=-hide_banner -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt+fastseek -analyzeduration 100M"
    set "pre=%pre% -probesize 50M -hwaccel dxva2 -y -threads 3 -v error -stats"
    set "global="
    set "video=-c:v h264_nvenc"
    set "audio=-c:a ac3"

    if defined ac3 if defined h264 call :both
    if not defined ac3 call :either
    if not defined h264 call :either
)

:both
echo %name% already in x264 + AC3 format.
goto :EOF

:either
if not defined h264 (
    echo Already has AC3 audio.  Re-encoding video only.
    set "audio=-c:a copy"
) 

if not defined ac3 (
    echo Already has h264 video.  Re-encoding audio only.
    set "video=-c:v copy"
)

echo "C:\ffmpeg-4.0.2-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg %pre% -i "%file%" %global% %video% %audio% "%drive%%dir%%name%.new.mkv""
echo del "%file%" /f /q
echo ren "%drive%%dir%%name%.new.mkv" "%name%%ext%"
goto :EOF

@end // end Batch / begin JScript

var stdin = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(0),
    htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    JSON;

htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
htmlfile.close(JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON);

var obj = JSON.parse(stdin.ReadAll());

for (var i = obj.streams.length; i--;) {
    if (/h264/i.test(obj.streams[i].codec_name)) WSH.Echo('h264=true');
    if (/ac3/i.test(obj.streams[i].codec_name)) WSH.Echo('ac3=true');
}
```

ffprobe Output for h264

```
{
    "programs": [

    ],
    "streams": [
        {
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "height": 528
        },
        {
            "codec_name": "aac"
        }
    ]
}
```

output for ac3

```
{
    "programs": [

    ],
    "streams": [
        {
            "codec_name": "h265",
            "height": 528
        },
        {
            "codec_name": "ac3"
        }
    ]
}
```

output for both ac3/h264

```
{
    "programs": [

    ],
    "streams": [
        {
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "height": 528
        },
        {
            "codec_name": "ac3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [batch file / JScript hybrid script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45089879/3074564) written by [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo) is not designed for recursive execution on all *.mkv and *.mp4 files in a directory tree. For that reason I completely rewrote the batch file and omitted the JScript script parts.

It looks like information about height of video output by `ffprobe` because of option `"stream=codec_name,height"` is not really needed here because every video should be processed independent on its height. For that reason `"stream=codec_name"` on `ProbeOptions` definition line should be enough for this task to reduce output of `ffprobe` by one line.

The JSON output of `ffprobe` can be processed in this use case also directly with **FOR** loop using as delimiters comma `,`, colon `:`, left square bracket `[`, **horizontal tab** <kbd>TAB</kbd>, right square bracket `]`, left `{` and right brace `}` and **normal space** <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. Lines starting with `{` can be completely ignored on processing the JSON formatted output. A case-sensitive string comparison is used to find out if the line contains a `codec_name` value with interpreting first coder/decoder value as video codec and second as audio codec.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ProgramFolder=C:\ffmpeg-4.0.2-win64-static\bin"
set "ProbeOptions=-v quiet -show_entries "stream^^=codec_name" -of json"
set "MpegOptions=-hide_banner -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt+fastseek -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 50M -hwaccel dxva2 -y -threads 3 -v error -stats"
set "FilesFound=0"
set "FilesEncoded=0"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.mkv *.mp4 /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    set "FullFileName=%%I"
    set "TempFileName=%%~dpnI_new%%~xI"
    set "AudioCodec="
    set "AudioOption=ac3"
    set "VideoCodec="
    set "VideoOption=h264_nvenc"
    set /A FilesFound+=1

    for /F "eol={ tokens=1,2 delims=,:[ ]{} " %%B in ('""%ProgramFolder%\ffprobe.exe" %ProbeOptions% "%%I""') do (
        if "%%~B" == "codec_name" (
            if not defined VideoCodec (
                set "VideoCodec=%%~C"
                if "%%~C" == "h264" set "VideoOption=copy"
            ) else (
                set "AudioCodec=%%~C"
                if "%%~C" == "ac3" set "AudioOption=copy"
            )
        )
    )

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(
    echo File: !FullFileName!
    echo Video codec: !VideoCodec!
    echo Audio codec: !AudioCodec!
    if not "!VideoOption!" == "!AudioOption!" (
        "%ProgramFolder%\ffmpeg.exe" %MpegOptions% -i "!FullFileName!" -c:v !VideoOption! -c:a !AudioOption! "!TempFileName!"
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            move /Y "!TempFileName!" "!FullFileName!"
            if not errorlevel 1 set /A FilesEncoded+=1
        )
        if exist "!TempFileName!" del "!TempFileName!"
    )
    endlocal
)

if %FilesFound% == 1 (set "PluralS=") else set "PluralS=s"
echo(
echo Re-encoded %FilesEncoded% of %FilesFound% video file%PluralS%.
endlocal
pause
```

**Attention:** The whitespace between `[` and `]` must be in batch file a tab character!

The batch file first sets up a local environment with enabled command extensions as required for this batch file and disabled delayed environment variable expansion to be able to process correct also files with one or more exclamation marks in file name or file path.

Next some environment variables are defined for usage later in the script. Something special is the definition of variable `ProbeOptions` because of argument string `"stream=codec_name"` which later must be passed to a separate command process started by **FOR** requiring double escaping the equal sign with two `^` to finally have `=` passed to `ffprobe.exe`.

The outer **FOR** executes once in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line:

```
dir *.mkv *.mp4 /A-D-H /B /S 2>nul
```

**DIR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** of this command process

- only the file names because of `/B`
- of non-hidden files because of `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- matching either wildcard pattern `*.mkv` or `*.mp4`
- in current directory and all its subdirectories because of `/S`
- with full path also because of `/S`.

It could be that no matching file name is found resulting in an error message output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR**. This error message is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures all lines output to **STDOUT** of background command process and processes them after started `cmd.exe` terminated. So **FOR** is processing a list of full qualified file names not changing while running the loop.

On drives with NTFS it would be also quite safe to use:

```
for /R %%I in (*.mkv *.mp4) do (
```

This results also in processing all non-hidden *.mkv and *.mp4 files in current directory and all subdirectories. NTFS returns the list of files sorted alphabetically. But this approach is problematic on FAT32 and ExFAT drives because of the code executed in every iteration of the loop could result in updating file allocation table. FAT32 and ExFAT return file names matching specific criteria simply as currently stored in file allocation table on which last modified file in a directory is always at bottom of the directory table. This means the list of file names could change while the loop runs on first, second, third, ... file name returned by FAT32 and ExFAT file systems. This could result in processing a video file more than once and skipping others. So it is better to process a list of file names which is loaded completely in memory before loop iteration starts.

**FOR** with option `/F` skips by default empty lines not output by **DIR** in this case and lines starting with a semicolon which is also not possible here because every line starts with drive letter `C`. But **FOR** would split up every captured line into substrings (tokens) using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and would assign just first space/tab separated string to specified loop variable `I`. This behavior is not wanted here as needed is always the full qualified file name even on containing one or more spaces. For that reason `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters resulting in turning off completely the string splitting behavior and get assigned to loop variable `I` always the file name of a found *.mkv or *.mp4 file with path, name and extension.

Following happens on every loop iteration:

1. The full qualified file name of current *.mkv or *.mp4 file is assigned to environment variable `FullFileName`.
2. The full qualified file name of current *.mkv or *.mp4 file with `_new` inserted left to file extension is assigned to environment variable `TempFileName`.
3. The environment variable `AudioCodec` is deleted if existing from a previous iteration of the loop.
4. The environment variable `AudioOption` is defined with string value `ac3` being the wanted audio codec.
5. The environment variable `VideoCodec` is deleted if existing from a previous iteration of the loop.
6. The environment variable `VideoOption` is defined with string value `h264_nvenc` being the wanted video codec.
7. The environment variable `FilesFound` is incremented by one with a simple arithmetic expression evaluated by command **SET**.

Then one more **FOR** is used to run the `ffprobe` command line with `cmd.exe /C` in background. In this special case it is necessary to enclose the entire command line in double quotes because of argument string `"stream=codec_name"` for getting the entire command line passed correct to additional command process started by **FOR**.

The inner **FOR** captures the output written by `ffprobe` in JSON format to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes this output line by line. Of interest are only the lines containing `"codec_name"`. Therefore option `eol={` is used to ignored completely all lines starting with `{`. Option `tokens=1,2` results in getting assigned first substring assigned to specified loop variable `B` and second substring to next loop variable `C` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). The list of delimiters specified with option `delims=` results in getting more or less just property name enclosed in double quotes like `"codec_name"` and its value also enclosed in double quotes like `"h264"` assigned to the loop variables `B` and `C`.

If the string assigned to loop variable `B` without double quotes explicitly enclosed in double quotes is case-sensitive equal the string `"codec_name"`, then this line is of real interest. The codec value assigned to loop variable `C` is assigned without double quotes to either environment variable `VideoCodec` or `AudioCodec` depending on video codec already found in JSON output in one of the processed lines before. Additionally the video or audio option used perhaps later is set to `copy` on video or audio codec being already the wanted codec `h264` respectively `ac3`.

It is necessary to enable delayed environment variable expansion after processing the output of `ffprobe` to be able to process the values of environment variables defined before in same command block. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

Output is first an empty line with `echo(` and next full qualified file name of current video file and its current video and audio codec.

The **IF** condition compares case-sensitive the video and audio option. The two option strings are identical only if current video file is already h264/ac3 encoded in which case both environment variables have `copy` as value. So if the two compared strings are **not** identical, the video files must be re-encoded with `ffmpeg` to change video codec or audio codec or both codecs.

The re-encoding of the video file was successful on `ffmpeg` exiting with an exit code **not** greater or equal `1`, i.e. with value `0`. In this case the temporary video file created by `ffmpeg` is moved over current video file with overwriting the existing video file if current video file is not write-protected by read-only attribute or NTFS permissions.

These actions result in updating file allocation table on FAT32 and ExFAT drives which is the reason for outer **FOR** running **DIR** to get a list of video file names into memory before loop iterations.

The environment variable `FilesEncoded` is incremented by one of the original video file could be replaced really successfully by a re-encoded version.

The temporary video file created by `ffmpeg` on existing at all after execution of `ffmpeg.exe` is deleted finally in case of any error resulting in this file still existing after the other command lines.

Finally, after processing all non-hidden *.mkv and *.mp4 files, a summary information is output using the two counter environment variables and initial environment is restored before halting batch file execution to be able to see all the output on having started the batch file with with double clicking on it.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`